# Stopping Time, Random Walk

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

I'm trying to solve this problem and don't know where to start. If someone could prove it or tell me how or point me to any relevant information I'd very much appreciate it.

Let $(s_n)_{n\geq0}$ be a 1-dimensional, unbiased random walk. For $a\in\mathbb Z^{*}$, let $T_a=\inf\left\{n\geq0:s_n=a\right\}$. Prove that $\mathbb E(T_a)=\infty$.

Comment: How much do you know about stopping times, or martingales?

Comment: Haven't heard of stopping times, I know the definition of martingales. Googling.

Comment: There was an error in the first version of my answer; I've corrected it, and it requires less knowledge of random walks now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we restrict to $a\in\mathbb Z^+$, the expected first hitting time $t_a=\mathbb E(T_a)$ has to satisfy the recurrence

$$
t_a=1+\frac12\left(t_{a-1}+t_{a+1}\right)\;.
$$

Since we can solve this for $t_{a+1}$, there can't be a least $a$ for which $t_a$ is infinite, so $t_a$ is either finite for all $a$ or infinite for all $a$. If it's finite for all $a$, it has to solve the above recurrence. The solutions are $t_a=-a^2+ma+n$, which would imply negative first hitting times for sufficiently large $a$. It follows that $t_a$ is infinite for all $a$.

Comment: Thanks Joriki, that makes so much more sense now.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you tell me how you found that recurrence?

Comment: @Chris: No matter which way you go, it takes you one time step. With probability $\frac12$ you end up at a distance $a-1$ from $a$, and with probability $\frac12$ at a distance $a+1$. The expected times to first reach $a$ from these positions are $t_{a-1}$ and $t_{a+1}$ respectively. By linearity of expectation, you just have to add up these contributions weighted by their respective probabilities. But I like Didier's solution better because it's more obvious that $t_1=1+t_1$ implies that $t_1$ is infinite than that the solution to my recurrence has a quadratic term with negative coefficient.

Comment: Completely understood. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $E[T_a]<\infty$ then $E[S_0]=E[S_{T_a}]$ by optional sampling since $S_n$ has bounded increments. Thus, we derive the contradiction $0=E[S_0]=E[S_{T_a}]=a>0$.

Answer (score 3):

By symmetry, it suffices to show that $T_1$ is not integrable. But $T_1=1$ with probability $\frac12$ and, also with probability $\frac12$, $T_1=1+T'+T''$, where $T'$ and $T''$ are i.i.d. copies of $T_1$. To wit, if $S_1=1$, $T_1=1$ but, if $S_1=-1$, one already spent one step to go to $-1$ and now one must come back to $0$, which takes $T'$ time steps, and again go to $+1$, which takes $T''$ time steps. Thus,
$$
\mathbb E(T_1)=\tfrac12\cdot1+\tfrac12\cdot(1+\mathbb E(T')+\mathbb E(T''))
$$
Note that the identity above is entirely rigorous as long as one only adds nonnegative terms, finite or infinite. Now, use $\mathbb E(T')=\mathbb E(T'')=\mathbb E(T_1)$ to get $$\mathbb E(T_1)=1+\mathbb E(T_1)$$ and note that this last identity **has a unique solution** in $\overline{\mathbb R_+}=[0,+\infty]$, which is $$\mathbb E(T_1)=+\infty$$
Perhaps more constructively, the identity above also completely determines the distribution of $T_1$ since, for every $s$ in $(0,1]$, it yields $$E(s^{T_1})=\tfrac12\cdot(s+s\cdot E(s^{T_1})^2)$$ which shows that $$E(s^{T_1})=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-s^2}}s$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Did. I'm working to understand it.